# x86-64 assembly: why offset 25 bytes?

Tags: c++, assembly

I started learning x86 assembly today by analyzing the assembly code corresponding to this c++ example (I know there exists something like `atoi` but I wanted to keep the example minimal):

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> range(int N) {
    std::vector<int> v(N);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        v[i] = i;
    return v;
}

int main() {
    return range(100).back();
}
```

If compiled with `g++ -O0 -S -fno-stack-protector return_by_value.cpp`, this results in this excerpt:

```
... <snip>
_Z5rangei:
.LFB509:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
    .cfi_lsda 0x3,.LLSDA509
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .cfi_offset 3, -24
    movq    %rdi, -40(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -44(%rbp)
    leaq    -25(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZNSaIiEC1Ev
    movl    $0, -24(%rbp)
    movl    -44(%rbp), %eax
    movslq  %eax, %rsi
    leaq    -25(%rbp), %rcx
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rdx
    ... <snip>
```

I was surprised to see an odd (i.e. not multiple of 8) offset: `leaq -25(%rbp), %rax`, especially since it is a `q` instruction and further we have also `-24(%rbp)`. **For what reason is the compiler reading across 8 byte boundaries?**

Comment: https://godbolt.org/ is a excellent resource for exploring the code generated by compilers

Comment: While it doesn't actually happen here, unaligned access *is* usually legal in x86

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at this fragment:

```
leaq    -25(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZNSaIiEC1Ev
```

`_ZNSaIiEC1Ev` is demangled to `std::allocator<int>::allocator()`, so `-25(%rbp)` is the address of an `allocator<int>` object which is passed to the constructor. If we print the `sizeof` of this object in GCC we will get 1. Since the size of the object is 1, there is no need to align it to 8 bytes and it can be placed in any memory address.

The `-24(%rbp)` which you see later is the address of a different object, and the compiler is not reading across an 8-byte boundary.

Note that the `lea` instruction does not actually access memory - it only calculates an address. Therefore, the fact that it has a `q` suffix does not mean that it accesses 8 bytes.